# Explanation upon Positive integer solution (Topic: Inclusion-Exlusion)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

How many positive integer solutions are there for the equality:

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 1000$$

such that:
$$ x_1 < 100$$

Solution:

$$\binom{1000 - 1}{ 5 - 1} - \binom{1000 - 99 - 1}{5 - 1}$$

Now what i don't understand  is:

Why the solution doesn't start as
$\binom{1000}{5}$ but it starts as $\binom{1000-1}{5-1}$

Can you please give me explanation regarding this?

Thank You, Umer Selmani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work with smaller numbers.

Suppose we wish to find the number of positive integer solutions to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10$$
A particular solution corresponds to the placement of four addition signs in the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones. 
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance if we place addition signs in the second, third, fifth, and seventh spaces, we get
$$1 1 + 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 2$, and $x_5 = 3$.  The number of solutions is the number of ways we can select $5 - 1 = 4$ of the $10 - 1 = 9$ spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones in which to place an addition sign, which is
$$\binom{10 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{9}{4}$$

Since a particular solution of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k$$
in the positive integers corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in the $k - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $k$ ones, the number of such solutions is
$$\binom{k - 1}{n - 1}$$
Make sure you understand why the formula works since some authors reverse the roles of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: I'd say most authors reverse the roles of $n$ and $k$. $n>k$ for all choices of $k$ after all.